# How to install iTerm2 without admin privileges?

Tags: macos, github, iterm2

I am using a machine running MacOS Sierra where I don't have admin access and have repeatedly tried to download iTerm2 but I only get an error telling me that "All downloaded files cannot be opened as they are damaged and should be moved to the Trash". This is presumably because I don't have admin privileges but I've been unable to find a good workaround. Installing with brew has also failed for the same reason.

Comment: https://google.com/search?q=mac+os+x+allow+apps+downloaded+from+anywhere

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably have to have admin access. Provided you have physical access to the computer you should be able to boot into safe mode and give your account admin access.

Check out this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password

Comment: I am not able to gain admin access at this time as it isn't my computer. My question was asking for a suitable workaround that won't require admin access.